# I already have an appbar but another one?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I already have an appbar, but another one appears above it on some devices please help

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('images/eat.gif'),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Anime Slash',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: 'SansitaSwashed'),
          ),
          Text(
            'انمي سلاش',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40.0,
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 2.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: img]

Comment: what is the source code or code snippets for this screen

Comment: if you use app bar in scaffold and use other widget all appear.

Comment: I put the code in the question

Comment: Try swipe safearea with scaffold

Comment: Can you include parent widget where you are putting this widget?

Comment: it is not work .

Comment: delete Safe area from body andd make it above Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

If the parent widget have appbar it will show it. Just parent widget app bar or child app bar